# Fazer duas consultas em uma mesma tabela em MySql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, select

Tenho uma tabela em banco MySql onde irei fazer uma consulta. Essa consulta precisa ser feita da seguinte maneira:

Para quem possui um plano no site:

- Permitir buscar por: nome, categoria (tabela diferente), endereço, bairro (tabela diferente), palavras chaves;

Para quem não possui plano ou esta com o plano vencido:

- Permitir buscar por: nome;

Vale lembrar também que para ambas as consultas devem ser relacionadas com a cidade selecionada na entrada do site.

É possível fazer uma consulta unica que me traga o resultado que preciso.

Answer (score 1):

A sua pergunta ficou meio ampla, mas saindo do princípio de que você já tenha esse formulário pronto, que a cidade selecionada no site está persistida em memória e que estar com o plano vencido ou não seja uma informação que já esteja pronta para ser utilizada, você pode fazer o seguinte:

**Para aqueles que possuem plano válido**

Você pode utilizar os [scopes do Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) para encadear uma série de condições:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  scope :by_name, -> (name) { where(name: name) }
  scope :by_category, -> (category) { where(category: category) }
  scope :by_address, -> (address) { where(address: address) }
  scope :by_neighborhood, -> (neighborhood) { where(neighborhood: neighborhood) }
end
```

O consumo fica algo:

```
# todos com o nome "Vinicius" e bairro "Jardins"
MyModel.by_name("Vinicius").by_name("Jardins")

# todos com endereço "7th Ave" ou bairro "Hell's Kitchen"
MyModel.by_address("7th Ave").or.by_neighborhood("Hell's Kitchen")
```

> [O suporte ao método `#or` só está disponível a partir do Rails 5.2.](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b0b37942d729b6bdcd2e3178eda7fa1de203b3d0)

Se quiser fazer [buscas parciais com `LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html), é só ajustar os escopos para:

```
scope :by_name, -> (name) { where("name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%") }
```

É a melhor forma de fazer buscas parciais em textos com Active Record, evitando [injeção de SQL](https://rails-sqli.org/).

**Para aqueles que não possuem plano ou está vencido**

Com os escopos criados, fica mais simples pesquisar por nome:

```
MyModel.by_name("Vinicius")
```

**Performance e N+1**

Para evitar as [queries N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-select-query-issue), carregue previamente as associações que for comparar, no seu caso `categoria` e `bairro`, ou simplesmente compare com o ID.

Com os escopos, ele sempre vai fazer uma query só, da forma que foi escrito. Se quiser ter certeza do que está sendo executado no banco de dados, pode utilizar o método [`#to_sql`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql):

```
MyModel.by_name("Vinicius").to_sql
=> "SELECT * FROM my_model WHERE name = 'Vinicius'"
```

Se você não conseguiu atingir o nível de performance que precisa, sugiro que deixe os helpers do Active Record e [escreva o SQL](https://blog.castle.co/tech/10-06-2016/complex-sql-in-rails):

```
PaymentDetail.find_by_sql(<<-SQL 
  SELECT * 
  FROM payment_details
  INNER JOIN projects 
          ON projects.id = payment_details.project_id
  ORDER BY payment_details.created_at DESC
SQL)
```

Queries mais complexas tendem a deixar o código Ruby muito difícil de ler, e às vezes até prejudicial. Isso acontece na maioria dos ORMs. Nesses casos, opto por escrever o SQL.